# Github action not updating, leading to "Warning: Unexpected input(s) ..., valid inputs are [...]"

Tags: github-actions

For some reason, the github action I'm working on isn't updating. Whenever I add new arguments to the action, it still uses the old action

Here's the action.yml file: (stored at `.github/actions/godot-build/action.yml`)

```yaml
name: Build Godot
description: Build Godot with the provided options.
inputs:
  pre:
    description: Runs before scons command
    default: ""
  target:
    description: The scons target (debug/release_debug/release).
    default: "debug"
  tools:
    description: If tools are to be built.
    default: false
  tests:
    description: If tests are to be built.
    default: false
  platform:
    description: The Godot platform to build.
    required: false
  sconsflags:
    default: ""
  scons-cache:
    description: The scons cache path.
    default: "${{ github.workspace }}/.scons-cache/"
  scons-cache-limit:
    description: The scons cache size limit.
    # actions/cache has 10 GiB limit, and GitHub runners have a 14 GiB disk.
    # Limit to 7 GiB to avoid having the extracted cache fill the disk.
    default: 7168
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Scons Build
      shell: sh
      env:
          SCONSFLAGS: ${{ inputs.sconsflags }}
          SCONS_CACHE: ${{ inputs.scons-cache }}
          SCONS_CACHE_LIMIT: ${{ inputs.scons-cache-limit }}
      run: |
        echo "Building with flags:" ${{ env.SCONSFLAGS }}
        ${{ inputs.pre }} scons p=${{ inputs.platform }} target=${{ inputs.target }} tools=${{ inputs.tools }} tests=${{ inputs.tests }} ${{ env.SCONSFLAGS }}
        ls -l bin/
```

But when I use it, via a step like this:

```yaml
      - name: Compilation (bits=64)
        uses: ./.github/actions/godot-build
        with:
          pre: "PATH=/home/hp/tmp/x86_64-godot-linux-gnu_sdk-buildroot/bin:$PATH"
          sconsflags: ${{ env.SCONSFLAGS }} ${{ env.MONO_SCONSFLAGS }} ${{ matrix.sconsflags }} bits=64 ${{ matrix.build-mono && 'mono_prefix=$HOME/mono-installs/desktop-linux-x86_64-release' || '' }}
          platform: linuxbsd
          target: ${{ matrix.target }}
          tools: ${{ matrix.tools }}
```

I get the error

```bash
Warning: Unexpected input(s) 'pre', valid inputs are ['target', 'tools', 'tests', 'platform', 'sconsflags', 'scons-cache', 'scons-cache-limit']
```

Is it possible for Github to cache actions? If so, how can I clear this cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was extracting a tar.gz file into the current directory, which caused it to replace my custom github actions file with it's own github actions file. I fixed this by adding the `--exclude=".github"` flag to the tar command.

Comment: Hi,

I just want to thank you for taking the time and explaining your issue. I had a very similar issue and I was banging my head on it for a few months without understanding. Your explanation made me realise that I was doing something quite similar (involontarly cachine the .github directory alonside other data). Thanks a lot !